# Json encode Arrays value

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, api

How to assign to a json value all values from particular array keys.

```
$cars = Array ( [0] => Array ( [category] => Most Selling [title] => BMW [price] => 20000 ) [1] => Array ( [category] => Most Selling [title] => Jeep [price] => 15000) [2] => Array ( [category] => Most Selling [title] => Lexus [price] => 18000  ) )

foreach ( $cars as $car) {
     $data = [
    'model' => 'new',
    'company' => $car['title'],
];
}
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Now when i output $json i get:

```
{"model":"new","company":"Lexus"}
```

Why it doesn't assign all title values like this?

```
{"model":"new","company":"BMW, Jeep, Lexus"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should proiduce the output you need.

```
$data = [
    'model' => 'new',
    'company' => '',
];
foreach ( $cars as $car) {
     $data['company'] .= $car['title'] . ', ';
}

$data['company'] = substr($data['company'], 0, -2); // remove last comma and space
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Why not just implode() ?

Comment: I like Rakesh's answer better, but glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `foreach` Loop for that. You can use `implode` and `array_column`

```
$data = [
  'model'   => 'new',
  'company' => implode(', ',array_column($cars, 'title'))
];
echo $json = json_encode($data);
```

Live demo : https://3v4l.org/9IrW8

Comment: implode by a comma and a space to get the exact output ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [];
foreach ( $cars as $car) {
     $data[] = [
        'model' => 'new',
        'company' => $car['title'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: that won't produce the output he's looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
$companyString = implode(', ', array_column($cars, 'title'));

$data = [
   'model' => 'new',
   'company' => $companyString
];

$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it